Приложение в Google Play и альтернативный метод оплаты для России
Вижу в Google Play приложение от нероссийского издателя в котором реализованы платежи через Google Play Billing Library.
Но если у устройства, где запущено приложение, российский IP, то способ оплаты меняется на какой-то российский мерчант, принимающий российские карты.
Это разрешено политикой Google? Внутри своего аккаунта разработчика (Финляндия) я нахожу возможность добавить альтернативные платежные системы только для Южной Кореи.
